# Why are GPIO permissions different in C program from console?

Tags: c, permissions, gpio

I think I'm running the same functionality in a C program as on the console, but I have permissions problems setting a GPIO direction.

These console commands, run as a normal user, work fine:

```
$ echo 436 > /sys/class/gpio/export
$ echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio436/direction
```

... while this code, in a C program (which I intend to have the same effect), fails:

```
...
  int gpioNumber = 436;
  /* Successful open... */
  FILE *exportNode = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/export", "w");
  if (exportNode == NULL) {
    printf("Unable to open /sys/class/gpio/export\n");
    return CT_GPIO_FAIL;
  }

  char buffer[100];
  sprintf(buffer,"%i",mGpioNumber);
  if (fprintf(exportNode, buffer) != (strlen(buffer)))
    {
      printf("Error writing to /sys/class/gpio/export\n");
      return CT_GPIO_FAIL;
    }

  fclose(exportNode);
  /* At this point the node /sys/class/gpio/gpio436 exists - I can see it in the console. */

  // Set the pin to be input or output by writing "out" to /sys/class/gpio/gpio[xx]/direction
  // I think this is the same file as gets opened in the second shell command.  
  printf("About to open direction.\n");
  sprintf(buffer,"/sys/class/gpio/gpio%i/direction",mGpioNumber);

  /* This line fails! */              
  FILE *directionNode = fopen(buffer, "w");

  /* .. and the error is reported. */
  if (directionNode == NULL) {
    int errnum = errno;
    printf("Unable to open %s. Last error: %s\n",buffer,strerror(errnum));
    return CT_GPIO_FAIL;
  }
```

This is the error report:

```
Unable to open /sys/class/gpio/gpio436/direction. Last error: Permission denied
```

If the direction node hasn't been created, I get a different error, so the reported permissions error seems to be accurately reported.

I run the program from the same console as the shell commands (after unexporting the GPIO, but without any other intervening actions.  The program runs without error using `sudo`.

Why aren't the permissions issues the same inside this C program run from the console, as they are in shell commands?  Am I missing a simple code error?

This is all running on a Jetson Xavier NX, Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: What are the permissions on the compiled binary?

Comment: FYI: the /sys/class/gpio interface has been deprecated after the introduction of libgpiod (in kernel version 4.8 i believe). I would recommend to give it a try, because it has some very nice features. You can, for example, lookup chips and their lines by name, so you no longer have to use magic numbers like "gpio436" (provided that the chips/lines are named in the device tree). On devices with interrupt support you can also register a callback, which will be called when the state of a particular line (or set of lines) changes.

Answer (score 0):

Well ... It does work as written, with the addition of a few milliseconds of sleep between "export" and trying to open the direction node.  Apparently the creation of the direction node isn't synchronous in the write to export, at least on this system.

I apologize for the noise.

Comment: Forget about this obsolete ABI, use character device and `libgpiod`. Much easier and doesn't need strange hacks.